# Probability Question using two probabilities

Tags: probability

There are two jars. Jar one has 4 red chips and  6 black chips. Jar 2 has 5 red chips and 5 black chips. What is the probability that a person will select the same color chip after selecting one chip from each jar?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

First pick from Jar one. Then you have a chip with some color. What is the probability a chip with that color is picked from Jar two?

Answer (score 0):

This is:

$$P(\text{Jar1:Red})P(\text{Jar2:Red}) + P(\text{Jar1:Black})P(\text{Jar2:Black})$$

which is:

$$\frac{4}{10}\frac{5}{10}+\frac{6}{10}\frac{5}{10}$$

$$=\frac{50}{100}$$

$$=\frac12$$

Comment: You really should not solve the whole thing when the OP has shown no effort at all.  How will they ever learn if you spoon feed them the answers.